# Pandas create new column using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pysimplegui

I'm trying to create a new column within one of my dataframes by combining existing columns through finding the values in a dictionary.

values["-R1-"] and values["-R2-"] are allocated a value through a listbox using pysimplegui which are a list of all column headings in the df.

If I put it the first row it works fine and created a new column.

`df['Unique_ID_Test'] = df["Account Code] + df["Transaction Id] + df['Abs'].astype(str)`

However if I try and find the value using a dictionary it gives me the below error message where it these should yield the same result.

`df['Unique_ID_Test'] = df[values["-R1-"]] + df[values["-R2-"]] + df['Abs'].astype(str)`

```
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (5253, 5255)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this won't work? The error message doesn't seem to be particularly helpful (for me).

Listbox code extract for reference

```
        [pg.Listbox(values=list, size=(60, 15), key='-Amt-')],
        [pg.Listbox(values=list, size=(60, 15), key="-R1-")],
        [pg.Listbox(values=list, size=(60, 15), key="-R2-")],
```

Comment: Maybe the value of `values['-R1-']` is a list ?!

Comment: You were absolutely right, I figured it out shortly afterwards. Put this as answer and I can give flag you as having the answer. Thanks for your help. @JasonYang

Comment: It's fine and answer is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered by Jason Yang above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).